# Laravel 5.1 pagination groupby links rendering

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.1

I am on Laravel Framework version 5.1.45 (LTS).

One club can have many events. I am trying to list all the events, group them by year and show one page per year.

According to my Laravel version documentation "Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually."

Here is my attempt to create the paginator manually and it seems to do the job:

```
public function index()
{
    $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() - 1;
    $perPage = 1;
    $events = new Paginator(Event::orderBy('date', 'desc')->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(date)'))->skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)->take($perPage + 1)->get(), $perPage, $page);
    $events->setPath(['events/events']);
    return view('events.index', ['events' => $events]);
}
```

And here is how I try to display the links at the bottom of the page.

```
{!! $events->render() !!}
```

If I remove the render bit, the page is displayed, albeit with no links. I can even go to the next page (year 2016) adding manually ?page=2 at the end of the url in my browser.

But if I leave the render bit in the index page, I get ErrorException in AbstractPaginator.php line 130: Array to string conversion.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think problem in `$events->setPath(['events/events']);`. Try to change it to `$events->setPath('events/events');`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. However the link on page 2 to the next page is `?page=2` which of course reload the same page. Time for another question I guess :(

Answer (score 1):

Hope this snippet can help

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::all()
        ->paginate($request->get('per_page', 25));

    $grouped_by_date = $posts->mapToGroups(function ($post) {
        return [$post->published_date => $post];
    });
    $posts_by_date = $posts->setCollection($grouped_by_date);

    return view('posts.index', compact('posts_by_date'));
}
```

Basically redefine the collection with the grouped collection.